# How Does Stack Overflow Replace State?

Tags: javascript

I'm a mac user and never use IE. But yesterday at work I went onto stack overflow and typed this into the browser using IE 9...

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349
```

And they replaced the URL to this without refreshing the page...

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page
```

I could not believe what I saw. Any ideas how stack overflow is able to utilize a functionality that mimics the history API's replace state on a browser that does not support it?

Comment: However SO does it, you can update browser URL via javascript without reloading using `window.history.pushState()`

Comment: @StevenMoseley Not on IE9 http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They actually redirect the user with a `301` redirection. Look at the headers:

```
GET /questions/824349 HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
[...]

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Sat, 08 Jun 2013 19:00:05 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 08 Jun 2013 18:59:05 GMT
Location: /questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sat, 08 Jun 2013 18:59:05 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect, i.e. it's done server side. You don't see a refresh because the browser doesn't open the first URL, it redirects right away to the second.

Here's the result on chrome's console.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How to implement a 301 redirect in the same way SO does it.

(Assumes there's a table called `questions` with columns `id` and `title`)

(Note: there's likely also heavy use of Memcached by SO rather than DB access for every page view, but that's another topic.)

For the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349
```

Your .htaccess will rewrite URLs in the format `questions.php?id=123&sef=abc-def`:

```
RewriteRule ^/questions/([0-9]+)/?([\w\-]*)$ /question.php?id=$1&sef=$2
```

Your question.php script

```
<?php
// Get the posted id (as int to prevent sql injection)
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;

// Get the posted search-engine-friendly title string (if any)
$sef = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['sef'] : '';

// Connect to the database
mysqli_connect(...);

// Get the question with the provided id
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = {$id}");

// If a question was found
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Find the SEF title for the question (lowercase, replacing 
    // non-word characters with hyphens)
    $sef_title = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '-', $row['title']);

    // If the generated SEF title is different than the provided one,
    if ($sef_title !== $sef) {
        // 301 the user to the proper SEF URL
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com/question/{$id}/{$sef_title}");
    }
} else {
    // If no question found, 302 the user to your 404 page
    header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com/404.php");
}
```